# Why are set objects ignored when encountered by JSON.stringify()?

Tags: javascript, json, set

I have a Student Java Script object as follows:

```
function Student(name, grade){
    this.name = name;
    this.grade = grade;
}
```

I know I can store and retrieve this object to/from Local Storage using **JSON.stringify()** and **JSON.parse()** method. It works fine. But my problem is below.

I want to introduce a new property '*subjects*' of **Set()** type that takes unique values and store this Student object in Local Storage. My *saveStudent()* method is as follows:

```
function saveStudent () {
    student = new Student("Rajib","1st");

    var subjects = new Set();
    subjects.add("Mathematics");
    subjects.add("Science");
    subjects.add("English");
    console.log(subjects);
    student.subjects = subjects;

    window.localStorage.setItem("student", JSON.stringify(student));
}
```

I can store this object in Local Storage without any error and also my console displays the 3 subjects properly. But when I try to retrieve this Student object from Local Storage, I get Student object with all the values except '*subjects*' which is empty. May I know why?

My *getStudent()* method is as follows:

```
function getStudent () {
    var student = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("student"));
    console.log(student);
}
```

My console shows

```
Object { name: "Rajib", grade: "1st", subjects: {} }
```

Is there anyway to store nested object(where property of object contains another object) as such in Local Storage and retrieve with all its properties and values?

**Note:** I can solve the above by serializing to String of Subjects and then deserializing again. But I want to avoid that and want to do it in pure Java Script or OOPs way.

Comment: This question has a perspective that the _duplicate_ doesn't share. @RLD, the OP, doesn't understand that issue lies in the nature of the `subject` property - it being a `Set`.

However, the poster of the linked question understands that `Set`s cannot be stringified simply, and is looking for a way to achieve that.

We can consider this post with a bit more empathy, and thus use the opportunity to educate for improvement.

Comment: Thanks @Igwe Kalu for being considerate. You are right, I thought from nested object perspective, but the problem lies in Set object.

Answer (score 5):

Because [**`Sets`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) in JavaScript don't store its entries as enumerable properties, the entries are not transparent to the [**`JSON.stringify`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function.

However, by the [`replacer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) parameter of [**`JSON.stringify`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and the [`reviver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) parameter of [**`JSON.parse`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), provisions are given for a means to influence how an item encountered in the serialisation/deserialisation process is handled.

Hence:

- **Storing your data**, use [**`JSON.stringify`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)'s [`replacer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) to transform the `Set` to an array --> [**`Array.from( Set( ... ) )`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- **Retrieving the stored data**, use [**`JSON.parse`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)'s [`reviver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) to transform the array back to a `Set` --> [**`new Set( [ ... ] )`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

---

```
function Student(name, grade, subjects) {
  this.name = name;
  this.grade = grade;
  this.subjects = subjects || new Subjects();
}

function saveStudent(student) {
  var studentObjectAsSerialisedData = JSON.stringify(student, function(propertyKey, propertyValue) {

    // Store a set in the form a list that can be used to recreate it
    if ("subjects" === propertyKey) {
      return Array.from(propertyValue);
    }

    return propertyValue;
  });

  window.localStorage.setItem("student", studentObjectAsSerialisedData);
  console.log("saved:", studentObjectAsSerialisedData);
}

function getStudent() {
  var studentObjectAsSerialisedData = window.localStorage.getItem("student");
  var student = JSON.parse(studentObjectAsSerialisedData, function(propertyKey, propertyValue) {
    // Restore subjects from list to the set form
    if ("subjects" === propertyKey) {
      return new Set(propertyValue);
    }

    // Everything else is returned as is
    return propertyValue;
  });

  student.subjects = new Set(student.subjects);

  console.log("loaded: ", student);
  console.log("loaded subjects of student: ", Array.from(student.subjects));
}

var subjects = new Set(["Mathematics", "Science", "English"]);
var student = new Student("Rajib", "1st", subjects);
saveStudent(student);

var storedStudent = getStudent();
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason of this is that `JSON.stringify(set)` always returns `'{}'`. You should pass `JSON.stringify` method replacer function to convert set of subjects into array like this: `Array.from(set)` and then save this version. Then after getting student object from localstorage you should convert subjects array back to set. So your code should look like this:

```
function saveStudent () {
    student = new Student("Rajib","1st");

    var subjects = new Set();
    subjects.add("Mathematics");
    subjects.add("Science");
    subjects.add("English");
    console.log(subjects);
    student.subjects = subjects;

    var stringifiedVersion = JSON.stringify(student, function (key, val) {
        if (val instanceof Set) {
            return Array.from(val);
        }
    })

    window.localStorage.setItem("student", stringifiedVersion);
}

function getStudent () {
    var student = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("student"));
    student.subjects = new Set(student.subjects);
    console.log(student);
}
```